# DataGrid/View thing for WebMatrix

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, razor, webmatrix

Yesterday I was on the microsoft webmatrix site looking at the docs, and I saw this thing on the right of the page, I think it was a tutorial or something for some kind of gridview thing for Webmatrix. Although I was interested I didn't take much notice of it as I was reading stuff about Razor. But now I'have spent all day and all night trying to find it again, (even visiting the same page), but I can't. All I can find is a few 3rd party open source things that don't look so friendly.

Does anyone know which one I'm refering to? Have you seen it/used it?

Answer (score 5):

Finally!

I found it. It's the WebGrid.Helper.

Can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/6-displaying-data-in-a-grid

Comment: Tutorial has been moved... try this one instead: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/ has some good articles on how to expand the use of the webgrid helper that might be of interest.